# Header issue on mobile

Tags: css

The site is http://www.oahu-hawaii-luau.com/
My header doen't come on small mobile screens but I can see it when I make my desktop window smaller. 
So it seems the issue is only with Mobile and Safari. The issue appears on screens smaller than 984px.

My logo header code is:

```
.logo-logobg {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 1260px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: url(images/logo-logobg.png) left top no-repeat;
}
```

I narrowed down the problem to the mobile navigation. The error is in this code but still cant figure out what exactly:

```
.nav-mobile {
    display:block;

}
.nav {
    width:100%;
    padding:0px 0 0 0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999999;
    top:53px;

}
.nav-list {
    display:none;
}
.nav-item {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    background-image:none;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}
.nav-item:hover {
    background-image:none;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}
.nav-item > a {
display:block;
color:#ffffff;
padding:8px 16px;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:14px;
border-bottom:1px solid #276815;
margin:0px;


height:auto;
line-height:normal;

border-radius:0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you attach screenshot? Looks fine on my chrome simulator

Comment: On Chrome it is fine but not on Safari

Comment: @Parlanchina there are numerous issues with this site. It looks like you're using ASP Web Forms, wrapping a page in a form tag is brutal. You also have a bunch of CSS being injected in the middle of the page instead of in the header. There's also the issue of using depreciated or outdated markup like `<div align="center">`. Using `align` on a DIV is now obsolete. Browser vendors are generous and continue to allow markup like this to work, but are under no obligation to do so. If this is a new site, I strongly suggest using HTML5 and brushing up on valid markup and practices.

Answer (score 1):

put this in your head: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure that <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> has anything to do with it. I also have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 in my header.

Comment: Your viewport meta tag is in the body element line 45. It should be in the head element

Comment: You are also declaring a HTML 4.0 Transitional doctype while using HTML5 mark up

Comment: You are right that this is one of the issues on the site. But after testing it is not fixing the problem above. thanks though.